# Question about of the proof from Lemma 3.2.42 in the book Set theory. On the structure of the real line

Tags: real-analysis, set-theory

Suppose that $f\in\omega^\omega$ is an incrasing function. For $x\in2^\omega$ define $x_f\in2^\omega$ as $x_f(n):=x(f(n))$ for all $n$.

I do not understand the following proof from Lemma $3.2.42$ in the book Bartoszyski and Judah: Set theory. On the structure of the real line.

1. If $f\in\omega^\omega$ is an incrasing function, then any $s,t\in2^{<\omega}$
   $$\mu(\{x:(x,x_f)\in[s]\times[t]\})\leq2^{-|s|-|t|+f^{-1}(|s|)}$$
   where $\mu$ is the measure for the Cantor space.
2. Why we can find an increasing function $f_A\in\omega^\omega$ such that $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}2^{|f^{-1}_{A}(|s_n|)|}2^{-|s_n|-|t_n|}?$$
   where $\dot{A}\subseteq \bigcap_{k\in\omega}\bigcup_{n>k}[s_n]\times[t_n]$ and $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}2^{-|s_n|-|t_n|}<\infty$ for sequences $\{s_n, t_n:n<\omega\}\subseteq2^{<\omega}$

Someone give me any suggestions how I can prove  it

Comment: Hello David C. Ullrich I already made the corrections

Comment: Ok, now what do the notations $\langle x,x_f\rangle$, $[s]$ and $[t]$ mean?

Comment: David C. Ullrich $[s]=\{x\in2^\omega:t\subseteq x\}$ for any $t\in2^{<\omega}$. Similarly $[s]$

Comment: That makes no sense. Did you maybe mean $[t] = \{x : t\subset x\}$? And is there some reason you're not willing to give the definition of $\langle x, x_f\rangle$?

Comment: David C. Ullrich, I had a mistake $[t]=\{x:t\subseteq x\}$ I think $\langle x,x_f\rangle$ as $(x,x_f)$